# Is there an OpenCV function to copy all pixels under a mask into an array?

Tags: opencv

I would like to find the median color in a masked area in OpevCV. Does OpenCV have a function that takes an image and a mask, and puts only the pixels from the image where mask != 0 into an array or `Mat`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any OpenCV function that creates a vector from masked values, I have written my own function to do that in the past, which you could do.

Alternatively you could calculate the histogram and find the median off of that, if your data is uint8.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following function of the Mat class to copy all the pixels into another Mat by using Mask:

```
Mat rst;
img.copyTo(rst, mask);
```

Answer (score 1):

Post is quite old now, but - as there is still no function available in OpenCV - I implemented it for my app. Maybe will be useful for anyone...

```cpp
cv::Mat extractMaskedData(cv::Mat data, cv::Mat mask)
{
    CV_Assert(mask.size()==data.size());
    CV_Assert(mask.type()==CV_8UC1);

    const bool isContinuous = data.isContinuous() && mask.isContinuous();
    const int nRows = isContinuous ? 1 : data.rows;
    const int nCols = isContinuous ? data.rows * data.cols : data.cols;

    const size_t pixelBitsize = data.channels() * (data.depth() < 2 ? 1 : data.depth() < 4 ? 2 : data.depth() < 6 ? 4 : 8);

    cv::Mat extractedData(0, 1, data.type());

    uint8_t* m;
    uint8_t* d;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
        m = mask.ptr<uint8_t>(i);
        d = data.ptr(i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < nCols; ++j) {
            if(m[j]) {
                const cv::Mat pixelData(1, 1, data.type(), d + j * pixelBitsize);
                extractedData.push_back(pixelData);
            }
        }
    }

    return extractedData;
}
```

It returns `cv::Mat(1,n,data.type())` where `n` is the number of non-zero elements in `mask`.

May be optimised by using image-type-specific `d` pointer (e.g. `cv::Vec3f` for `CV_32FC3` instead of generic `uint8_t* d` together with `const cv::Mat pixelData(1, 1, data.type(), d + j * pixelBitsize);`.